# ReactJS: How do I pass data from JSON in local storage to a component?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I've been trying to get the values of JSON data that i've set into the local storage. I've then tried to access this data (which is in the APP.js state) from the Food.js file using a .map function . The values returned are only in the alert in APP.js which is [object Object],[object Object],[object Object] and then it says .map is not a function. WOuld you guys know what's going on?

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Food from './Food.js';
import Form from './Form.js';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    var testObject = [
      {title: "Pumpkin Pie", ingredients: ["Pumpkin Puree", "Sweetened Condensed Milk", "Eggs", "Pumpkin Pie Spice", "Pie Crust"]},
      {title: "Spaghetti", ingredients: ["Noodles", "Tomato Sauce", "(Optional) Meatballs"]},
      {title: "Onion Pie", ingredients: ["Onion", "Pie Crust", "Sounds Yummy right?"]}
    ];

  localStorage.setItem('testObject', JSON.stringify(testObject));

    this.state = {
      apple:localStorage.getItem('testObject')
    }
    alert(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('testObject')));
}

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div id="app">
          <div>
            <ul>
              <Food ingTitle={this.state.apple} />
            </ul>
          </div>

        </div>
        <Form />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

FOOD.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Food.css';
import FoodList from './FoodList.js';

export default class Food extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      isToggleTrue:false
    }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }


  handleClick(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    this.setState(prevState => ({
      isToggleTrue: !prevState.isToggleTrue
    }));
  };


  render() {
    return (
      <div className="Food">
        <li className="foods"><a href="#" onClick={this.handleClick}>asdfasdf</a>

          <FoodList name ="asdf" />
        </li>
        <div>{
          this.props.ingTitle.map((a,i) => {
            <li>{a.ingredients}</li>
          })
        }</div>
      </div>
    );
  }

}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While assigning the item to `state` from `localStorage`, you need to also use `JSON.parse` since you use `JSON.stringify` while setting the data in `localStorage`

```
this.state = {
  apple:JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('testObject'))
}
```

You get an error because while initialising state you have directly assigned the result from `localStorage` to state which is a `string` and hence doesn't have a `map` method defined on it.

Comment: Thanks. It works. The .map function is not returning any value though : / it's just blank where it should be even though console.dir(this.props.ingTitle) brings the expected array

Comment: You forgot a return statement from inside the map function

Answer (score 2):

First, use [`console.log`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console)/`.dir` instead of `alert()`, for sanity. Eg. `console.dir(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('testObject')));` Then inspect the output in your browser's dev tools. Do you have a source map? If so you can also easily set breakpoints to inspect the code as it runs.

Second, you are parsing the JSON for the `alert`, but not when you set the state. Try:

```
this.state = {
  apple: JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('testObject'))
}
console.dir(this.state.apple);
```

Comment: It brought it back in the console thanks. Now the question is why in Food.js is the map function not returning the ingredients : ? hmm

Answer (score 0):

you need to parse json, try this

```
getItemsFromLocalStorage() {
  try {
    const items = localStorage.getItem('testObject');
    return JSON.parse(items, null, -1);
  } catch (err) {
    return []
  }
}
constructor(){
// .....
  this.state = {
        apple: this.getItemsFromLocalStorage()
    }
}
```